# Display all three colors (red/black/white) on an electronic paper display

Tags: c, nrf52832

I have been trying to drive a 2.13in electronic paper display (EPD) with an Adafruit nRF52 Bluefruit using the SSD1680 driver.

I converted the image to C-code using an online image-to-C-code [converter](https://www.digole.com/tools/PicturetoC_Hex_converter.php). I used this image to display:

[image]

Code :

```
    #include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
    #include "Adafruit_EPD.h"
    
    #define EPD_CS      4
    #define EPD_DC      3
    #define SRAM_CS     -1
    #define EPD_RESET   2 // can set to -1 and share with microcontroller Reset!
    #define EPD_BUSY    5 // can set to -1 to not use a pin (will wait a fixed delay)
    
    Adafruit_SSD1680 display(250, 122, EPD_DC, EPD_RESET, EPD_CS, SRAM_CS, EPD_BUSY);
    
    uint8_t gImage_IMG_0001[4000] = { 0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xf1,0xfc,0x78,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0x1f,0x87,0xc3,0xf7,0xcf,0xc3,0xff,0x87,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xf1,0xfc,0x38,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x0e,0x03,0x80,0xf7,0x8f,0x00,0xff,0x83,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xf1,0xfc,0x18,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xc6,0x63,0x18,0xe6,0x0f,0x18,0xff,0x83,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xe1,0xfc,0x18,0xf0,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xe3,0xfd,0xc7,0xe3,0x98,0xec,0x0f,0xb8,0xff,0x03,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x01,0xfc,0x08,0xe0,0x3f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xe3,0xff,0x8f,0xc3,0xf8,0xef,0xcf,0xf0,0xff,0x11,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x01,0xfc,0x40,0xc6,0x3f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xe3,0xff,0x0f,0xc3,0xe1,0xcf,0xcf,0xe1,0xff,0x31,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xf1,0xfc,0x60,0xc6,0x3f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0x3f,0xf1,0xc3,0xcf,0xcf,0xc7,0xfe,0x00,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xf1,0x8c,0x60,0xc6,0x33,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xe3,0xfc,0x7e,0x71,0x87,0xdf,0xcf,0x8f,0xfe,0x00,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xf1,0x8c,0x70,0xc0,0x31,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xe3,0xf8,0x06,0x03,0x00,0x5f,0xcf,0x00,0xfc,0x38,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xf1,0x8c,0x78,0xe0,0x71,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xe3,0xf8,0x07,0x07,0x00,0x1f,0xcf,0x00,0xfc,0x7c,0x7f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x06,0x3f,0xfc,0x38,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x83,0xc0,0xf0,0x3f,0xc0,0xf0,0x3c,0x0f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x1e,0x07,0x81,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x06,0x3f,0xfc,0x38,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x11,0x84,0x62,0x1f,0xc4,0x60,0x18,0x07,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf0,0x0c,0x47,0x11,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xc2,0x3f,0xfc,0x18,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0x39,0x8c,0x63,0x1f,0xfc,0x7f,0x18,0xc7,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf1,0x8f,0xe7,0x38,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xc2,0x01,0xfc,0x08,0xe0,0x7f,0xfc,0x7e,0x39,0xfc,0x7f,0x1f,0xfc,0x7f,0x1f,0xc6,0x31,0x88,0xc2,0x3f,0x8f,0xc7,0xf1,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x06,0x01,0xfc,0x00,0xc2,0x3f,0xfc,0x7e,0x38,0xf8,0xfe,0x3f,0xf8,0xfc,0x3f,0x8f,0x03,0x80,0xe0,0x7f,0x1f,0x87,0xe1,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x06,0x11,0xfc,0x40,0xc7,0x3f,0xfc,0xfe,0x39,0xe1,0xf8,0x70,0xf8,0x7e,0x1e,0x1f,0x07,0xc1,0xf0,0x7c,0x3f,0x83,0xc3,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x1e,0x39,0xfc,0x60,0xc7,0x3f,0xff,0xfe,0x39,0xc3,0xf1,0xf0,0xfe,0x3f,0x9c,0x3f,0x07,0xc1,0xf0,0x78,0x7f,0xe3,0x8f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xfe,0x39,0xfc,0x70,0xc6,0x31,0xfc,0x7f,0x31,0x80,0x60,0x1f,0xcc,0x23,0x18,0x07,0x03,0x80,0xe0,0x70,0x0c,0x63,0x00,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xfe,0x39,0xfc,0x70,0xe0,0x71,0xfc,0x7f,0x03,0x80,0x60,0x1f,0xc0,0x70,0x18,0x06,0x21,0x88,0xc6,0x30,0x0c,0x06,0x00,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xff,0x39,0xfe,0x78,0xf9,0xf1,0xfc,0xff,0xc7,0x80,0x60,0x1f,0xf1,0xfc,0x78,0x06,0x71,0x1c,0x47,0x30,0x0f,0x1e,0x00,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0x1f,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0x3f,0xff,0xe7,0xff,0xff,0xe3,0xc1,0xf9,0xbc,0x3e,0x3e,0xff,0x3f,0xc7,0xfd,0xfd,0x9f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x07,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0x3f,0xff,0xe7,0xff,0xff,0xe3,0x9c,0xf9,0x38,0x0c,0x9d,0xfe,0x3f,0x01,0xf5,0x79,0xcf,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xc7,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0x3f,0xff,0xe7,0xff,0xff,0xe3,0x7f,0x70,0x10,0x0c,0x99,0xfc,0x1f,0x11,0xf0,0x79,0xcf,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x7e,0x39,0x11,0x8e,0x03,0xe1,0xe7,0xf1,0xff,0xe2,0xc1,0x40,0x10,0x7c,0x9b,0xfc,0x9f,0x13,0xf8,0xf1,0xc7,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x0e,0x31,0x00,0x06,0x01,0x80,0xe7,0xf1,0xff,0xe2,0x99,0x32,0x38,0x3e,0x13,0xf8,0xcf,0x87,0xfa,0xf3,0xc7,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0x07,0x33,0x00,0x06,0x31,0x9c,0x67,0xf1,0xff,0xe6,0xbb,0x32,0x7c,0x0f,0xf4,0x3f,0xff,0x07,0xff,0xf3,0xe7,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc3,0x13,0x18,0xc6,0x31,0x1c,0x67,0xff,0xff,0xf6,0xbb,0x40,0x1f,0x0f,0xec,0x9f,0xfe,0x20,0x7f,0xf3,0xe7,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0xe3,0x83,0x18,0xc6,0x31,0x1c,0x67,0xf1,0xff,0xe2,0xbb,0x40,0x10,0x47,0xc9,0x9f,0xfe,0x30,0xff,0xf3,0xe7,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x07,0x87,0x18,0xc6,0x01,0x80,0xe7,0xf1,0xff,0xe2,0x80,0xe6,0x70,0x0f,0xdc,0x9f,0xfe,0x00,0x7f,0xf3,0xc7,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xfc,0x0f,0xc7,0x18,0xc6,0x03,0xc1,0xe7,0xf1,0xff,0xe3,0x7f,0xe6,0xfc,0x1f,0x9c,0x3f,0xff,0x02,0x7f,0xf3,0xc7,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc7,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x9c,0x7f,0xff,0x7f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf1,0xcf,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0x0f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc1,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf9,0xcf,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0x1f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xfd,0x9f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xf8,0x30,0x70,0x60,0xc1,0xc1,0x83,0x07,0x0e,0x0c,0x1c,0x38,0x30,0x70,0xe0,0xc1,0x83,0x83,0x06,0x0e,0x0c,0x18,0x38,0x30,0x7f,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xc0};
        void setup(void) {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      Serial.print("Hello! EPD Test");
    
      display.begin();
      Serial.println("Initialized");
    
      display.setRotation(2);
    
    }
    
    void loop() {
     
      Serial.println("Displaying Image");
      display.clearBuffer();
    
      uint16_t x = 0;
      uint16_t y = 0;
      display.fillScreen(EPD_RED);
      display.drawBitmap(x, y, gImage_IMG_0001,  250 , 122, EPD_WHITE);
    
      display.display();
      
      delay(20000);
    }
```

It gives this result:

[image]

From this I understand that the online conversion tool neglected the red pixels and considered them white, and black text became red as I used the `display.fillScreen(EPD_RED);`.

1. Is there any tool to make mono B/W and mono-red from an image (as said in the EPD datasheet)?
2. How can I combine those two files to make all three colors display at once?

Libray used:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_EPD
https://www.adafruit.com/product/4195

Comment: Where's the link to the display datasheet? Add it into your question (rather than in the comments).

Comment: You told it to draw this image in white. I suppose if you want to use drawBitmap starting from a red fill, you will have to call it twice - to draw the black pixels, and also draw the white pixels.

Comment: @user253751 If I use drawBitmap fucntion again it overwrites the previous image and shoes only latter called one only

Comment: [The drawBitmap function with one colour](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library/blob/master/Adafruit_GFX.cpp#L783) doesn't change the pixels where the bit is 0 - the last colour you set to those pixels should stay there.

Comment: @user253751 That is exactly what I need, 2st image while I print then '1' bits gets set and '0' become somewhat like transparent and let he previous state of that of that particular bit as it is. The function I'm using more like clear the 0 bits of bitmap.

Comment: The function you are already using doesn't clear the 0 bits

Comment: I didn't get what you meant but I'll explain whats happening 
1. Suppose if I set a bit HIGH at (0,0), while displaying a picture 
2. Then I display another picture which has (0,0) bit 0 (LOW)

So the result is (0,0) bit LOW, whatever happens in last called function is remains

Comment: Just use a different conversion tool. [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+bitmap+image+to+c+array). [This one](https://javl.github.io/image2cpp/) for example lets you set the threshold which it uses to determine if the output pixel should be black or white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in the library isn't for three color images simultaneously.
So we need to edit the library function to take input from two separate files of the Black-White component (Red considered White) and Red-White Components (Black considered White).

For this you need an image converter, I wrote code in python(it's pretty simple) which goes through each pixel of the image, checking for Black-White for output in the "b-file" bitmap and Red-White for output in "r-file' bitmap.

These two bitmaps will be an argument to the "DisplayTricolor" function. This function looks for each bit in both the files

Case 1: if finding '0' in the r-file means the background color will be Red

Case 2: if there is '0' in the b-file means the background color would be Black.

Note: Case 1 and Case 2 can't exist together if your python code (image to hex) works fine.

This way you call the inbuild library function "drawBitmap" with the selected background color from case 1 or case 2 and

White for all '1' in bitmap files common in both cases.